# Using CSS to change appearance of input fields causes distortion in height/width

Tags: html, css, input, textbox

So... the heights and widths aren't aligning once I add a border to my input fields.  All text fields show some distortion when I apply a border to them....

The long, red boxes are 167 x 21 pixels.

The long, normal boxes are 168 x 23 pixels.

[image]

I've played around with a lot of different stylings but I can't seem to find one that always works for all my boxes.  This includes playing with the font units, padding of the boxes, specifying an exact width and height, specifying margins...

Current styles:

```
   input[type=text] {
       font-family:courier;
       font-size:80%; 
       padding: 0.1em;
   } 

   input.error_required { 
       border: 1px solid red; 

       font-family:courier;
       font-size:80%; 
       padding: 0.1em;
   }
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this to happen... it's not the most horrible thing in the world but I'd like to correct it, if I can.

second example:
[image]

excessive styles that produced this:

```
   input[type=text] {
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0.1em;
      height: 20px; 
      margin: 0.1em;

   } 

   .input_error_required { 
      border: 1px solid red; 
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0.1em;
      height: 20px; 
      margin: 0.1em;
   } 

   .input_error_unique { 
      border: 1px solid orange; 
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0.1em;
      height: 20px; 
      margin: 0.1em;
   }
```

html is just basically this repeated:

```
<input name='real_server_name' type='text'></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name='real_server_ip' type='text'></input>
```

Comment: what happens if you have a default `border: 1px solid #ccc` for all input boxes?

Comment: You know how the HTML box model works, right?

http://www.redmelon.net/tstme/box_model/

Comment: Can you also create a fiddle please?

Comment: @Diodeus not really, I don't do a lot of front end.  Everywhere I saw online that described how to add a border didn't seem to mention any of the issues I'm having.

Comment: @dnagirl ->  put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting a default border for all input boxes: `1px solid #ccc`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the height explicitly?

```
input[type="text"] {
    height:23px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

The `border-box` stuff is to ensure that the height is reflected regardless of border. Its kind of a best practice to do it on everything, but figured I would point it out here as well.

Edit: it sounds like you actually need to apply the `border-box` thing more than the explicit height! I recommend both, though.

Comment: i will try using `border-box` but like I said in the question, using a specific height did not solve the problem.

Comment: oh, i'd like to have a CSS2 compatible solution... and it looks like border-box is just margins and padding.  One of the solutions I'm working with is just seeing if I can find the right amount of borders and padding.

Comment: border-box isn't CSS3 ... it works all the way back to IE8. In fact, this exact problem was the reason it was invented.

Comment: sorry, google lead me to [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) (which is css3) instead of border-box.  I have to support IE6 & IE7 if at all possible, though.  I did try using the border-box attribute and my browser wouldn't render the whole input style with it there (using most recent version of chrome) anyway... dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue writing a rule for the normal style..

here yo go..

http://jsfiddle.net/wyzqV/

this is the css im using

```
input[type=text] {
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0px;

      margin: 5px;
      width: 167px;
      height: 22px;

   } 

.normal { 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0px;

      margin:0px;
    width: 168px;
      height: 23px;
   } 

   .input_error_required { 
      border: 1px solid red; 
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0px;

      margin:0px;
    width: 168px;
      height: 23px;
   } 

   .input_error_unique { 
      border: 1px solid orange; 
      font-family: courier;
      font-size:   80%; 
      padding:     0px;

      margin: 0px;
    width: 168px;
      height: 23px;
   }
```

Comment: answer is for @dnagirl cuz she said it first...!  (and my css is extremely sloppy, btw, I was just going at it in 'full attack mode' trying to get the stupid thing to align... I hate aligning text boxes, btw)

Comment: actually i edited my answer, he explains what i did, i made a Fiddle. anyway, you goit it nice